# MVVM Constructor Learning

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hi I am trying to learn C# WPF MVVM. So I have a class with the following constructor

Model Class

```
public BillMetaData(bool isKey, string attName, int attType, bool isRequired, int attLoc, int attLength, int isDecimal, int attAlignment) {
    _isKey = isKey;
    _attName = attName;
    _attType = attType;
    _isRequired = isRequired;
    _attLoc = attLoc;
    _attLength = attLength;
    _isDecimal = isDecimal;
    _attAlignment = attAlignment; }
```

Now I have my ModelView has follow, its not connected with a database yet, I am just trying to understand the pattern.

```
    bool isKey = true;
    string attName = "Name";
    int attType = 1;
    bool isRequired = true;
    int attLoc = 1;
    int attLength = 30;
    int isDecimal = 1;
    int attAlignment = 1;

    private BillMetaData obj = new BillMetaData( isKey, attName, attType, isRequired, attLoc, attLength, isDecimal, attAlignment);

    public string TxtCustomerName
    {
        get { return obj.attName; }
        set { obj.attName = value; }
    }
```

However when creating the BillMetaData I get the following errors

```
a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field
```

From my ViewModel folder I reference my Model as follow

```
using Project.Model;
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the rest of the `BillMetaData` class. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call parameterized constructors with instance variables in a field initializer. For that matter, you can't use instance variables **at all** in field initializers.

If you need to invoke the constructor like that, do it in a *method* (say, your constructor or an Init routine).

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    private BillMetaData obj = new BillMetaData( isKey, attName, attType, isRequired, attLoc, attLength, isDecimal, attAlignment);   
}
```